# FragmentPagerAdapter and It's Fragment contextMenu issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager -> FragmentStatePagerAdapter subclass -> ListFragment subclass chain. When I want to delete item via context menu in the current ListFragment it also deletes the first item in the adjacent ListFragments. And if i want to clear current ListFragment then it clears the adjacent ones. I don't understand why does this happen. How can i fix this?

Here's code of my Adapter:

```
 mPagerAdapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) 
        {

            @Override
            public int getItemPosition(Object object)
            {
                return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position)
            {
                    return ProductListFragment.newInstance(position);

            }

            @Override
            public int getCount()
            {
                return mLists.size();
            }

        };
```

And here's code for my ListFragment subclass:

```
public class ProductListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    public static final String LIST_POS = "com.zulfigarov.shoppingassistant.list_id";
    private ProductList mList;
    private ProductAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int pos = args.getInt(LIST_POS);
        mList = ListHolder.get().getLists().get(pos);

        adapter = new ProductAdapter(mList);

        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    @Override
    public ProductAdapter getListAdapter()
    {
        return adapter;
    }


    private int selectedItemIndex;

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        if(v.getId() == getListView().getId())
        {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            selectedItemIndex = acmi.position;

            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu_for_list, menu);
        }


    }

    public void showAddingProductDialog()
    {
        NewProductDialogFragment dialog = NewProductDialogFragment.newInstance();
        dialog.setTargetFragment(ProductListFragment.this, NewProductDialogFragment.CREATE_NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST);
        dialog.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "add_new_product");
    }

    public void showChangingProductDialog(int index)
    {
        NewProductDialogFragment dialog = NewProductDialogFragment.newInstance(mList.get(selectedItemIndex));
        dialog.setTargetFragment(ProductListFragment.this, NewProductDialogFragment.CHANGE_PRODUCT_REQUEST);
        dialog.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "change_product");
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case(NewProductDialogFragment.CREATE_NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST):
            {
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    String prodName = data.getStringExtra(NewProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME),
                           prodMeasure = data.getStringExtra(NewProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE),
                           prodAmount = data.getStringExtra(NewProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT);


                    addNewProduct(new Product(prodName, prodAmount, prodMeasure));

                }
                break;
            }

            case(NewProductDialogFragment.CHANGE_PRODUCT_REQUEST):
            {
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    String prodName = data.getStringExtra(NewProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME),
                           prodMeasure = data.getStringExtra(NewProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE),
                           prodAmount = data.getStringExtra(NewProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT);

                    changeProductAtIndex(selectedItemIndex, new Product(prodName, prodAmount, prodMeasure));

                }
                break;
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    public void addNewProduct(Product prod)
    {
        mList.add(0,prod);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void changeProductAtIndex(int index, Product prod)
    {
        mList.set(index, prod);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case(R.id.clear_current_list):
            {
                mList.clear();
                break;
            }

            case(R.id.delete_current_list_item):
            {
                mList.remove(selectedItemIndex);
                break;
            } 

            case(R.id.edit_selected_item):
            {
                showChangingProductDialog(selectedItemIndex);
            }
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setDivider(null);
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
        lv.setSelector(R.drawable.list_item_selector);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Product prod = mList.get(position);

        CheckBox isBought = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.is_bought);
        isBought.setChecked(!isBought.isChecked());
        prod.setBought(isBought.isChecked());

        if (prod.isBought())
        {
            mList.remove(position);
            mList.add(prod);

        } else
        {
            mList.remove(position);
            mList.add(0, prod);

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static ProductListFragment newInstance(int pos)
    {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(LIST_POS, pos);
        ProductListFragment prodListFrag = new ProductListFragment();
        prodListFrag.setArguments(args);

        return prodListFrag;
    }

    class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>
    {

        public ProductAdapter(ProductList list)
        {
            super(getActivity(), 0, list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.prod_list_item, null);

            Product prod = getItem(position);

            TextView prodTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.prod_title);
            prodTitle.setText(prod.getTitle());

            TextView prodCount = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.prod_count);
            prodCount.setText(prod.getAmount() + " " + prod.getMeasure());

            CheckBox isBought = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.is_bought);
            isBought.setChecked(prod.isBought());

            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the value of POSITION_NONE?

Comment: It's -2. I use it to force FragmentStatePagerAdapter to reload all pager content on notifyDataSetChanged(). It seems like the only way to provide correct dynamic page deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaand after googling a bit more i've found the solution:

it seems that if you're using multiple ListFragment with ContextMenus you want to work separately for each fragment, then your onContextItemSelected should be like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

       if(getUserVisibleHint())
         {
             //Your code here
         }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
     }
```

hope this'll help you =)